# How to sort a data frame with values greater than

Tags: r

I used below method but it does not work.

```
mtcars[order(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$mpg > 30),]
```

Comment: What do you do with the other values? Drop them?

Comment: What does "sort a data frame with values greater than" mean???

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars <- mtcars[mtcars$mpg>30,] %>% 
      dplyr::arrange(mpg)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to drop all other values. If yes, try:

```
df <- mtcars[mtcars$mpg>30,][order(mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg>30]),]
```